# While loops and some help around loops

Tags: python

This is something that im trying to loop where if they do not input a b or c they will get the error output and will therefore have to go back to the question. Although this isnt working:
**UPDATED**

```
if get_bool_input("Do you wish to view the previous results from your class: "): #The 'get_bool_input' will determine if they input yes or no and will either open the file or not.
    selection= input("Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order(A), scores highest to lowest(B) or average score highest to lowest?(C)")
    while True:
        if selection not in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
            print ("Error, type in A, B or C.")
            break
        if selection == 'A':
            print (alphabetically(data))
            break
        elif selection == 'B':
            print (by_score(data))
            break
        elif selection == 'C':
            print (by_average(data))  
            break

else:
    input ("Press any key to exit")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Do you wish to view the previous results from your class: yes
Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order(A), scores highest to lowest(B) or average score highest to lowest?(C)n
Error, type in A, B or C.
```

I don't get the option to input another answer.

Comment: Any advance on *"this isnt [sic] working"*? A `SyntaxError`, presumably, but a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: That `return True` is probably hurting you. It would also help if you post the minimal complete code required to reproduce your problem. I think all of this code is inside some function, so please post the relevant parts f the function. The code as it stands should give you a `return outside function` error

Comment: What is not working?  Are you getting errors?  You may notice that your updated code put `return True` outdented from my answer.  If this is *not* in a function, you should use `break` instead, but it should be in line with all of the `if ...:` and `elif ...` lines.

Comment: I attempted to make a while loop but It failed, as in it didn't make sense at the start in my eyes. I was just working off examples. but trying to achieve the main concept of getting the output Error not valid and then the user can type in their answer again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have four problems: `return True` is not valid syntax outside of a function, even if it were it is between an `elif` and an `else`, `else: selection not in ['A', 'B', 'C']:` is not valid syntax, and you never redefine `selection`.  Perhaps you want something more like this:

```
while True:
    selection = input("Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order(A), scores highest to lowest(B) or average score highest to lowest?(C)")
    if selection not in ['A', 'B', 'C']:
        print ("Error, type in A, B or C.")
        continue
    if selection == 'A':
        print (alphabetically(data))
    elif selection == 'B':
        print (by_score(data))
    elif selection == 'C':
        print (by_average(data))  
    break
```

Comment: Your code gives me the error of 'return true' being out of the function.

Comment: That's why I said to use `break` if it isn't a function.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Your `else` statement will never be executed. Your `return True` statement cuts the execution flow there.

You might instead want this:

```
while True:
    selection= input("Do you wish to view the results in Alphabetical order(A), scores highest to lowest(B) or average score highest to lowest?(C)")
    if selection == 'A':
        print (alphabetically(data))
        return True
    elif selection == 'B':
        print (by_score(data))
        return True #replace this with 'break' if you're not inside a function
    elif selection == 'C':
        print (by_average(data))
        return True  
    else:
        print ("Error, type in A, B or C.")
```

Comment: This just gave me a syntax.